# Ingres sql - Syntax error on 'then', the correct syntax is:

Tags: sql, ingres

I  have some code in ingresql that doesn't seem to work. I tried this out in Postgres using the same type of problem and it ran just fine. Now when I try it out in ingres it has huge problems.

```
select sum(case when date_part('year', order_dt) = 2015 then invoice_amt else 0 end) last_yr
    ,sum(case when date_part('year', order_dt) = 2016 then invoice_amt else 0 end) sales
    ,s.group_cd
    ,sum(s.on_hand) on_hand
from invoicehist ih
left join invitemhist iih 
on iih.order_no = ih.order_no
left join stock s
on s.stock_no = iih.stock_no
where date_part('year', order_dt) >= 2015 and date_part('month', order_dt) = 1
group by s.group_cd
```

The error I get is:

```
Syntax error on 'then', the correct syntax is:  SELECT [ALL|DISTINCT] target_list FROM table(s) [WHERE serch_cond]
[GROUP BY col(s)] [HAVING] search_cond]
[UNION subselect] [ORDER BY col(s)]
```

Comment: Try `case date_part('year', order_dt) when 2015 then invoice_amt else 0 end` ?

Comment: Now it gives me a `SQL error#1 line1, Expecting more arguments`

Comment: The posted SQL works OK in Ingres 10.0.1, 10.1 and 10.2; are you using an older version of Ingres?